# Computed field - extension method, ViewModel, Viewbag variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following classes.

```
public class Header 
{ 
    public int HeaderId { get; set}
    public virtual List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
    .... 
}

public class Detail 
{ 
    [Required, ForeignKey("Header")]
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Header Header { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And I've built a page show the list of `Header`. I didn't use any ViewModel.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<App1.Models.Header>
@foreach (var i in Model) {
    ....
    // TODO: Add Sum of Detail.Quantity for each Header item
}
```

Now, I have a requirement of adding the sum of `Quantity` in the `Detail` class for each `Header` item in the `Index.cshtml` page.

What's the best and quickest way to refactor the code? Is an extension method on `Header` good approach?

P.S. I just use summing as an example, the actual computing is much more complex.

Comment: Can you just do the summing logic in the view?

Comment: @BenReich I just use summing as an example, the actual computing is much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just create a function and put it in `ViewBag`.

```
ViewBag.SumFunc = new Func<Header, int>(....);
```

Then call it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep the logic in the Model and not in the View. Since it's an aggregation of the Detail objects in the Header, I suggest you add the logic into the Header object.

```
public class Header
{
    public int HeaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Detail> Details { get; set; }

    public int SumOfDetailQuantities
    {
        get { return Details.Sum(x => x.Quantity); }
    }
}
```

I would not suggest that you add an extension method to the Header since you've already got full control over the Model, an extension method would only obfuscate the code. There is nothing wrong with having this type of aggregation logic in the Model, but if you have some religious reasons for not doing it, then set the value from the ViewModelBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

create a class

```
public class HeaderWithSum {
    public Header Header {get; set;}
    public int Sum {get; set;}
}
```

then in your Action Method :

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var hs as headerWithSum;
    List<HeaderWithSum> headerWithSum;
    List<Header> headers = headerRepository.GetAll();
    int sum = 0;
    foreach(var h in headers) {
        sum = h.GetSumOfDetails();
        hs = new HeaderWithSum()
             {
                 Header = h , Sum = sum
             };
        headerWithSum.Add(hs);
    }
    return View(headerWithSum);
}
```

for simplifying i omitted some code such as DI and Implementation of GetSumOfDetails method